# Excel Formula in Google Spreadsheet works but failed to compute accurately on local installed excel Office 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm using `=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$M,MATCH($O2,$A:$A,0),MATCH(P$1,$A$1:$M$1,0)),0)` formula in excel to bring the value from Table A to Table B based on maching headers.

The same formula works like charm on Google Spreadsheet but when I tried to run the same formula on my locally installed excel (office 2016) its not giving correct results

Strange isn't it!!!

anyone facing similar issues or whats the fix for it

regards

Comment: What results is it giving you? What results are you expecting? What does the data look like?

Comment: *"Strange isn't it!!!"* Hard to say... because we have no idea what your data is or if you are opening the same spreadsheet!!!

Comment: can you give a test case? some data

Comment: If you use the "Evaluate Formula" option to step through, does it show you where the error is introduced?  (While **I** would *assume* that it's one of the `MATCH`s, **you** can *confirm*)